# WordPress development administration menu CSS?

Tags: php, wordpress

Hi there I am creating a plugin for WordPress and I am at the stage of creating the CSS side of the administration menu. I have been reading the codex for WP but still not entirely sure how I can Implement the whole thing. Firstly I have two files **adminstyle.css** and **adminstyle.html**. I know I have to use wp enqueue style/script functions in WP but need some assistance on the actual implementation. Firstly the html/css side is a page for admin inputs/textareas/radio buttons for the admin to choose his/her settings. So my question is is there any WP CSS conventions or is it as simple as including a CSS/HTML script on the admin menu for the admin to choose his/her settings?

Answer (score 0):

Its not so hard to implement but you should aware to wordpress hooks, filters and technique to implement it.

If you want some code sample, then by default there is a file located in plugins directory with name `hello.php`, its a default `Hello Dolly` Plugin. Take a look on this sample that how to implement style on admin side:

```
function dolly_css() {
    // This makes sure that the positioning is also good for right-to-left languages
    $x = is_rtl() ? 'left' : 'right';

    echo "
    <style type='text/css'>
    #dolly {
      float: $x;
      padding-$x: 15px;
      padding-top: 5px;     
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 11px;
    }
    </style>
    ";
}

add_action( 'admin_head', 'dolly_css' );
```

In above codes `dolly_css` is a function which is attached to the [admin_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head) hook.

Comment: Does the admin_head hook link the css file to hello.php?

Comment: hello.php is your plugin file or whatever you give the name and `admin_head` hook will add css,js or whatever to add in admin panel through your plugin.